# JDBC Mysql Error?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a database on an Ubuntu server that I'm able to connect to using mysql -p[password] without any problem. It looks like it's connecting with 'root'@'localhost'. However, when I try to connect using this code snippet,

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ender", "root", "password");
```

I get an error telling me 'access denied'. The connection username is shown as 'root'@'ns22***.ovh.net' (Yes, it's OVH)

I'm assuming that the problem is due to it not coming through as root@localhost. Is there anything I can do to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried without `:3306`? Really though, you should not use root from a webserver. Unless you're itching to be hacked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running this command in the MySQL console

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'ns2*****.ovh.net' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```